# Search folder using name in txt file

Tags: python

I want to search a folder's which names have been provided in a text file. 
and want to read the file inside the folder(.txt) to do the check and generate the log in PYTHON.

txt file contains:

ABC.txt
nmz.txt

where ABC and nmz is a folder name.
So folder not having any extension inside the file name has been given like abc.txt where abc need to read from file and search in drive to find the folder

Comment: How does a folder have a `.txt` extension?

Comment: what you tried post here first so we can easily identified what you need actually

Comment: Folder not having .txt extension its a name given in the file example abc.txt where abc is a folder name.

Answer (score 0):

maybe this will help

```
myList = open("list.txt","r")
for line in myList:
    list = line.split(".txt")
    folderName=list
    print folderName
```